# How to check if int has a value

Tags: java

I have this code, to get the highest and lowest value in a array and later print out all values in rows of seven:

```
int hochstes;
int niedrig;
        int q = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 49; i++){
           if(hochstes == null){
               hochstes = array[i];
               niedrig = hochstes;
            }
           if(array[i] > hochstes){
               hochstes = array[i];
            }
           if(array[i] < niedrig){
               niedrig = array[i];
           }

           q++;
           if(q == 7){
               q = 0;
               System.out.println("");
            }else{
              String a = (i < 10) ? " " + i : "" + i;
              System.out.print(a + ": " + array[i] + "  ");
           }

        }
```

In line 4 im trying to check if `hochstes` yet has a value and if not i assign the first("second") value of the array to it! Of course it wont work to compare `hochstes` with `null` what should i use instead thanks!

Comment: An `int` always has a value and is never `null`.

Comment: What did i say? ` Of course it wont work to compare hochstes with null what should i use instead thanks! `

Comment: in your case initialize `hochstes` & `niedrig` with first element from array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since primitive types can't be `null`, you have to look at it another way.

The easiest solution is to simply assign it the first possible value outside the loop and continue the loop from the second value.

E.g.:

```
int hochstes = array[0];

// Loop from 1 to higher
```

As Peter Lawrey correctly remarks: you're starting your iteration at index 1. Index 1 is not the same as the first index, keep that in mind. Many (if not all) datastructures are zero-based which means they start at `0`, not `1`. That's why you see me assigning `array[0]` to get the first value.

Comment: This works if there is a first value or the array is not empty.

Comment: Yeah, the implicit assumption here is that at least 1 value is present. A check for this should be added in an actual implementation to avoid problems.

Comment: The OP appears to assume the first element is `[1]` as well !?

Comment: Good point, I've added a small note to reflect this properly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use sentinel values.  For a maximum, use Integer.MIN_VALUE and for a minimum use Integer.MAX_VALUE.

```
int hochstes = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int niedrig = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for(int i : array) {
    if(hochstes < i) hochstes = i;
    if(niedrig > i)  niedrig = i;
}
```

Using Integer(s) is much more expensive and could create an object for every element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Use the wrapper class

do

```
Integer hochstes = null;
```

and you can still do normal operations with hochstes like a normal int (comparing/ setting values, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You should always initialize your variables. One way to solve this can be using the first element in the array as the max/min element:

```
int hochstes = array[0];
int niedrig = array[0];
```

Other way is to initialize it with the minimum (or maximum) value available for your variable:

```
int hochstes = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int niedrig = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Value types can't be `null` in Java.

You would have to have a separate `boolean` variable, initialized to `false`. When you assign a value to `hochstes`, also set your boolean to `true`. Then check your boolean to see if the value has been initialized yet.

For this specific purpose, you could also initialize your max/min variables to the minimum/maximum possible values, respectively:

```
int hochstes = int.MIN_VALUE;
int niedrig = int.MAX_VALUE;
```

You can then skip the conditionals entirely.

Comment: in the code `int i;` i has no value. it is not 0, nor can it be operated on. int will only be assigned a 0 if it is an instance

Comment: @LoganMurphy Thanks, edited accordingly; I was thinking of a different language.